# Which Linux Distros or Desktop Environments deals with unresponsive apps best?

Tags: gui, desktop-environments, notification, dialog, distro-recommendation

For a person who needs stable and easy Linux GUI desktop experience, which "Linux Distros"/"Desktop Environments" has the feature to ask user through GUI to close an application if its unresponsive, if not, a visual feature which allow user to clearly see the unresponsive window/application with its changed color/text/graphics?
Optional Side Question: Which "Linux Distro"/"Desktop Environment" keeps other apps running if possible when some app unresponsive?

Comment: Please refer https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic, Ubuntu and *official* flavors of Ubuntu (https://ubuntu.com/download/flavours) are on-topic on this site, so all answers will be the same distribution (Ubuntu) with different desktops (ie. *flavors*).  Your question however is asking for *opinions* which are off-topic here (being better asked on Forums; this is a Q&A site); please read https://askubuntu.com/help/dont-ask

Comment: @guiverc will it be better to delete this question from askubuntu?

Comment: Gnome does that already. The default desktop environment of Ubuntu has this feature already. Whenever an app will freeze, it'll provide a GUI dialog box showing the error message and with a few options to troubleshoot.

Comment: FYI:  (*as question is closed I don't see issue going off-topic now*)    I don't see real differences between distributions; they're all GNU/Linux to me; the primary difference between the Ubuntu (Lubuntu *jammy*) I'm using now & opensuse (*tumbleweed*), fedora (*I forget*), debian (*bookworm*) is the software stack component ages... ie. just in on-topic Ubuntu; my *jammy* stack is very close currently to *impish* or 21.10 but it changes (20 packages now updating to non-impish as I type), but *impish* is different to *focal* (20.04), which differs even more to *bionic* (18.04) .. ie. stack age

Comment: Fedora is roughly equal to my current Ubuntu; as is Debian (though some components here on Ubuntu are newer but that'll change I hope in days...) with *tumbleweed* the newest as it's *rolling*. ie.  to me differences in distributions are just stack ages; some give choices like Ubuntu does, or with Debian I use *testing* (*bookworm*) but I could use *stable*, *old-stable* or even *old-old-stable* if I wanted...  ie. age of stack is what I consider important.  Yeah desktop matters; but my box has multiple DEs installed anyway & not much difference there either in my *opinion* !

Comment: FYI:  If confused by my reference to Ubuntu & mention of Lubuntu; I'm using LXQt or Lubuntu currently; but I consider it a Ubuntu box; I can just logout & login selecting a Ubuntu session (instead of Lubuntu I'm currently using) & it's a GNOME session; choose Xubuntu and it's an Xfce session...  ie. as stated I have multiple DEs installed so can decide on what I'll do on a particular day, which I'll use or what I think will best suit my expected workflow.

Comment: @guiverc thanks for all this information

Comment: FYI:  there is no reason for the distributions I mentioned, except they are what are installed on the box I'm using, or the box to my right & left [ie. proximity the only reason I used them as examples... I really don't know what Fedora it is; it changes every ~6 months & I've not kicked myself back to *rawhide* as currently I'd get no benefit from that  (*but will when it's useful*).  Debian *bookworm* is 12, *stable* is 11/Bullseye, *old-stable* is 10/Buster, *old-old-stable* is 9/Stretch etc. Note stacks vary; Ubuntu is mostly from *upstream* Debian but not always; why this Lubuntu is newer

Comment: If you discover an unresponsive/crashing application, please troubleshoot and --if appropriate-- file a bug report. This is open software; you are a *participant*, not a mere user. You have a role to help test and provide worthwhile feedback to improve the software. If you slack on that role, then the system doesn't work -- you're not making your contribution.

Comment: @user535733 thanks for info

Comment: @Someone please don't send opinion-based question to [linux.se]! This question would be closed there for exactly the same reasons it would be closed here!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Gnome already does this. This feature is already available in Ubuntu's default desktop environment. When an app freezes, it will display a GUI dialogue box with the error message and a few troubleshooting options.

The choices are as follows:

1. Force quit: Close the unresponsive application.
2. Report: Report a bug to the package maintainer (*This is only available with certain apps.*)
3. Wait: Be patient and wait for the application to respond.

[image: GUI dialog box.]

It will not only show the dialogue for applications, but also for services, extensions, themes, and other items if they become unresponsive.